# How to get the return value between two different c++ program using Visual Studio 2005

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio

Now, I have two programs A and B. Program A uses `system()` to execute program B.

But, the program B uses writing file way to return its execute result.

Has program A a better way to get the return value of program B?

For example

In program A

```
int main(){
    system("B.exe");
    readFile(finePath);
    //do something
    return 0;
}
```

In program B

```
int main(){
    char temp[1024];
    //do something
    writeFile(temp);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Show us what you have tried (minimalistic code).

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3470215/what-is-the-preferred-way-of-passing-data-between-two-applications-on-the-same-s - maybe you'll find some useful information there

Comment: The term "return value" is a bit confusing to me, so just to make sure. Your are not asking about "status code" from program B, right? The question is about getting various results/outputs that B produces, correct? Cause the "status code" is often returned directly by system(). See http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/system/

Comment: I updated a example. Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Pipes are a relatively simple, cross-platform way to do this without creating temporary files all over the place and having to deal with the additional issues that potentially arise from doing that.

```
static string pcommand(const string& cmd) 
{
    FILE* stream = _popen(cmd.c_str(), "r");
    string data;
    if (stream) 
    {
        while (!feof(stream))
        {
            const int buffer_size = 256;
            char buffer[buffer_size];
            if (fgets(buffer, buffer_size, stream))
                data.append(buffer);
        }
        _pclose(stream);
    }
    return data;
}

int main()
{
    string 'str' = pcommand("dir");
    // 'str' now contains the results sent to stdout
}
```

Comment: Yep: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/96ayss4b.aspx. I think normally on other platforms, you can avoid the underscore prefix.

Answer (score -1):

**Method 1.**

Try using the `ERRORLEVEL` system variable to check the return value of any running program.

Note:
ERRORLEVEL is a system variable so use it as [such](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2008/09/26/8965755.aspx)... ;)

**Method 2.**

You can use [Process.ExitCode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.exitcode.aspx) property.