# C++/Qt: Pass variables between C++ and Qt GUI without the C++ part including the Qt library

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface, parameter-passing

## Closed:

Thanks everyone for the ideas, will try to work with your provided suggestions so solve my problem!

## Problem:

"C++ main" (which CANNOT `#include QObject` or any Qt lib) gets data, processes the data and passes it into a separate Qt process (Qt GUI in this case).

Data gets visualized within the Qt GUI and provides feedback, e.g. you can send commands to the "C++ main" (like START/STOP MEASUREMENT).

[Visualization of the problem in best paint quality.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yyczb.png)

## Question:

Is there any possible way for the "C++ main" to get feedback from the Qt GUI **WITHOUT** including Qt in "C++ main" in any way? (The "C++ main" runs on an I/O-card which is not able to process/load the Qt lib.)

Thank you in advance for helpful answers!

Comment: So the command interface and the gui are actually separate programs, that you want to communicate somehow?

Comment: Somehow. Actually, the GUI is dependant on the MAIN but the MAIN is not dependant on the GUI (the MAIN should run without the GUI).

Comment: 1. It's Qt - not QT. 2. It is a process (not a file) 3. Which OS? Can you use shared memory? Can you use file-based communication? How do you implement the pulling mechanism on both sides?

Comment: Used OS is Windows 7 and file-based communication is possible but incovenient. The I/O-side is rather uninteresting, just focusing on the part where the C++ needs to get some sort of data/information from the Qt GUI without including Qt itself. Thought of queues and some sort of virtual functions but I don't know if this makes sense.

Comment: You said _The "C++ main" runs on an I/O-card which is not able to process/load the Qt lib_. Does this mean that your C++ code runs on one machine, and your Qt code runs on a different machine? What is the model of the I/O card?

Comment: I/O-card is used to get data from a scanner. C++ code and Qt code run on the same machine and display on the same monitor. Just want to pass data between GUI and MAIN with the requirement that the MAIN can't include Qt in any way.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3470215/what-is-the-preferred-way-of-passing-data-between-two-applications-on-the-same-s Read this.

Comment: Ok. When you said _"the MAIN can't include Qt in any way"_, do you mean there is a requirement that the GUI must run in a separate .exe?

Comment: I wanted to keep it in the same .exe but I don't know if this is even possible with the Qt GUI. If there is a way, please tell me, otherwise I will separate the problem and try to establish a communication between these two using Lazar's link.

Comment: It's possible, but first I'd like to understand: Why can't your main file #include any Qt headers?

Comment: So you want Inter-Process Communication. Start here to get overall picture: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication and then decide if you want to use sockets, shared memory or something else.

Comment: Thanks everyone for the comments, The Badger and code_fodder provided two different approaches for my problem, I will try to implement The_Badgers method first, if this doesn't work, I will use the communication approach. Thanks everyone for your answers, I'm rather new to C++ and just try to make this work, haven't found any solution on the internet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without much code on what goes on in your "C++ main" it is difficult to answer. But if you have class with a proper interface that is created in main and then used for the IO you could do something like the following:

```
class MyIoHandler {
public:
    enum Command {START, STOP};
    MyIoHandler() {}

    void command(Command command) { d_command = command; } // Set the command
    void getData(MyData& data) { data = d_data; } // Do a deep copy
private:
    void run() 
    {
        while(d_command == START) {
            readDataFromIO();
            d_data = data;
        }
    }
    Command d_command;
    MyData d_data;
};
```

Then the GUI just need to call the correct functions on the class to interface with the IO handler. There is no need for the main class to know how the GUI looks, but the GUI must know how the class looks.

This is also working on the assumption that they are in the same executable (from the comments) and

You just need to take care about threading etc.

But as mentioned, without some structure or code examples it is very difficult to give a useful answer.

Answer (score 0):

I normally use QUdpSocket (in the Qt world) to talk to my other apps (effectively for IPC). Then your c++ world you can use normal sockets `sys/socket.h` for the same job. Since your comms is simplistic - i.e. message passing this is quite easy to do. There is some effort creating your c++ / Qt class to handle your UDP, but from then on its really easy.

The main drawback for me is that the two programs have to agree on a port to use (The IP address would be loop back address 127.0.0.1). So you may have a configuration file, or a command line parameter to set this...